# OnPaste issue in quill with pasted content in this format <!--StartFragment-->

Tags: editor, clipboard, copy-paste, quill, clipboarddata

I am using onPaste function in quill editor. But whenever I tried to paste some text, the text get started as below format. How can I display them as the same content copied from?

Below is the code that I had used in order to get either html/text or plain/text

```
import Quill from 'quill'
const Clipboard = Quill.import('modules/clipboard')
const Delta = Quill.import('delta')

class PlainClipboard extends Clipboard {
   onPaste(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.quill.focus();
    const range = this.quill.getSelection()
    const text = e.clipboardData.types.find(type => type == "text/html") == "text/html" ? e.clipboardData.getData('text/html') 
                : e.clipboardData.types.find(type=>type == "text/rtf") == "text/rtf" ? e.clipboardData.getData('text/html') 
                : e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    const delta = new Delta()
      .retain(range.index)
      .delete(range.length)
      .insert(text)
    const index = text.length + range.index
    const length = 0
    this.quill.updateContents(delta, 'silent')
    this.quill.setSelection(index, length, 'silent')
    this.quill.scrollIntoView()
}
```

**Read highlighted "**Test**" content is copied and pasted but instead of displaying as it was before, the chuck of html code is displayed.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the whole point of this clipboard is to paste the contents as plaintext?

Your issue is that you're directly retrieving the `text/html` clipboard entry and just inserting it, which is always going to be raw HTML (that's the [whole point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#html) of it).

The way to fix your current solution is to just ask for `text/plain`, which will give you the plain text you're after:

```js
const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
```

That being said, I'd actually go with a different approach altogether. I wouldn't recommend rewriting the `Clipboard` module if you can avoid it. Instead, you should use the APIs Quill exposes, and use [clipboard matchers](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#addmatcher), which let you respond to the clipboard and modify the `Delta` that way.

For example, this matcher will strip all formatting on anything being pasted in by simply stripping the `attributes` property from the ops:

```js
quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.ELEMENT_NODE, (node, delta) => {
  const ops = delta.ops.map((op) => ({insert: op.insert}));
  return new Delta(ops)
})
```

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/alecgibson/pen/XWpBRgP).